# What is the standard order process workflow in Magento 1?

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1, sales-order, order-status, workflow

I'm trying to understand the order process in Magento 1.7. The background is: I'm extracting the payment (and later the complete checkout) from Magento to another system, but the order processing should take place in Magento. So, I need to understand, at what places in the process I can / need to define interfaces to my other application.

I expected to find quite quickly a workflow diagram for the order process, including also the payment. But could not find anything so far, what would be more or less complete and contain payment.

**What is the order process workflow (only for/with the Magento standard statuses), including the payment, in Magento 1?**